# Where and why do we use a reference to const?

Tags: c++, constants, ref

**Okay we have created a reference to Date So, that any change made in Date via this function**

**So, that the changes may reflect in main**

> but why do we make change if we hade declared it const ?

*What's benifit of using const*

````
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& d){
return os << '(' << d.year()
<< ',' << d.month()
<< ',' << d.day() << ')';
}
source : Programming : Principles and structure ```
````

Comment: Using a reference as a parameter is not only meant to be used to change its value, it also prevents compiler from generating a copy of the object, which may be expensive in some cases.

Comment: You use `const` when you *don't* want to make changes, merely inspect. And a `const &` is *usually* cheaper than copying the object.

Comment: Benefit of const that this object cannot be changed inside the function. Therefore, is somebody calls that function, she can be sure that the object won't be changed

Comment: Passing by reference avoids copying an object - which can be beneficial if the object is expensive to copy for some reason.   Passing by `const` reference allows the benefit of passing by reference with an assurance that the passed object will not be unintentionally changed.

Comment: I dunno why, but I suspect the trigger to this question is "why did making the reference `const` break this code?", and the likely answer is "because `year()`, `month()`, and `day()` were/are not marked `const`.

Comment: @WhozCraig - What you say may, or may not, be true.    If it is true, then the OP should have asked that specific question, rather than the one they asked.   There was certainly no indication in this question that the code sample worked if the `Date` argument was passed by value, but broke if the `Date` was passed by `const` reference.

Comment: this code is picked from book by stroustup itself and i had that question arised ,,,,, It must work perfectly